# How do I deal with an "invalid sender" error message when deploying a contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, remix

When deploying a smart contract, I get this message: "Error: invalid sender undefined." See details below.  Why is this happening?  What do I need to do differently?

I wrote the smart contract below and compiled it on Remix online IDE([this](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.10+commit.f0d539ae.js)).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is an password contract which included new,verify,delete,change password
// it also includes the user here.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
contract userPasswd
{
    mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) private  userPasswds ;
    event RecordReturnResult(bool res);

    /// @dev new the pair of user and password to the array here
    function newPair(string user, string password)  returns (bool) {      
        bytes32  sha3_user = sha3(user);
        bytes32  sha3_password = sha3(password);
        bool res = true;
        if (userPasswds[sha3_user] > 0) {
            res = false;
            RecordReturnResult(res);
            return res;
        }           
        else{
            userPasswds[sha3_user] = sha3_password;
            res = true;
            RecordReturnResult(res);
            return res;
        }      
    }

    /// @dev verify the pair of user and password stored in the blockchain
    function verify(string user, string password) returns (bool) {
        bytes32  sha3_user = sha3(user);
        bytes32  sha3_password = sha3(password);
        //userPasswd[sha3_user] = sha3_password;

        //check it
        if (userPasswds[sha3_user] == sha3_password){
            RecordReturnResult(true);
            return true;
        }           
        else{
            RecordReturnResult(false);
            return false;
        }
    }

     /// @dev delete the pair of user and password stored in the blockchain
    function del(string user) returns (bool) {
        bytes32  sha3_user = sha3(user);

        if (userPasswds[sha3_user] > 0){
           delete userPasswds[sha3_user];
           RecordReturnResult(true);
           return true;
        }
        else {
            RecordReturnResult(false);
            return false;   
        }

    }
      /// @dev change the pair of user and password stored in the blockchain
    function change(string user, string password) returns (bool) {
        bytes32  sha3_user = sha3(user);
        bytes32  sha3_password = sha3(password);

        if (userPasswds[sha3_user] > 0){
           userPasswds[sha3_user] = sha3_password;
           RecordReturnResult(true);
           return true;
        }
        else {
            RecordReturnResult(false);
            return false;
        }                
    }
}
```

After compiling in Remix, I copy the content of (the “Web3 deploy” text box) and paste it into the geth console. The content of the “Web3 deploy” text box is :

```
 var browser_queue_sol_queueContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"d","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addRequest","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"queueLength","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"popRequest","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_element","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ElementPopped","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_element","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ElementPushed","type":"event"}]);
var browser_queue_sol_queue = browser_queue_sol_queueContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '470000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

and the console shows:

```
Error: invalid sender undefined
undefined
```

the geth version is: Version: 1.6.6-unstable. go version is : go1.9beta2 windows/amd64

Comment: yes, it is ,but there is no answer, I need a answer please.

Comment: Hi there @jiebang. I'm afraid asking another duplicate question won't get the first question answered any more quickly. If you'd like to keep an eye on the other question, feel free to star it. For now I suspect that you're question will be flagged for closure as a duplicate, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Jiebang, I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of your July 7 post, but I upvoted the other post to give it more visibility.  I hope you get an answer.